# Apple watch not completely syncing messages

Tags: icloud, messages, data-synchronization, apple-watch

Messages sync properly (ie if I delete them from one they disappear from the other device) between my iPhone and MacBook, but never seem to be removed from my Watch.

- iPhone 13, Watch 7, all latest updates, all networking, iCloud and background refresh turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple Watch does not support syncing Messages in iCloud, which is the system that enables deletion to sync to other devices.

There is no documentation of this limitation from Apple, beyond the lack of mentioning the Apple Watch on their setup document for the feature, [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/set-up-messages-mm0de0d4528d/icloud).